# why need initial object and pushout to have coproduct. why not pushout by itself

Tags: category-theory

It seems to me that by definition, any pushout already includes a coproduct. But many texts seem to imply that only a pushout with an initial object has a coproduct. Is this true?

Answer (score 3):

You should check that a coproduct and a pushout over the initial object are the same. Coproducts may exist in categories without initial objects, but if a category has an initial object the two notions coincide. In fact, coproducts are guaranteed to exist if the category has all pushouts and an initial object; this is not the case without the second condition.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear to me what you have in mind when you say "any pushout already includes a coproduct", so let me just give a counterexample. Consider the category which has two objects and no morphisms except the identity morphisms.  This category has all pushouts, since the only way you can have a pair of maps $A\to B$ and $A\to C$ is if $A=B=C$ and the maps are the identity, in which case you can check that $A$ (with the identity maps again) is a pushout.  But this category does not have an initial object, nor does it have a coproduct of the two objects (since there is no object that both of them have maps to).

Comment: If you can collapse all 4 objects and 4 arrows of a pushout into one object with one identity map, why can't you collapse all 3 objects and 2 arrows of a coproduct into one object and one identity map?

Comment: You certainly can't "collapse" all the objects in a coproduct diagram to one object since you might be taking the coproduct of two different objects.

Comment: To say that "pushouts exist" means that for any three objects $A,B,C$ and any two morphisms $f:A\to B$ and $g:A\to C$, there exists an object $D$ and morphisms $p:B\to D$ and $q:C\to D$ which form a pushout diagram.   To say that "coproducts exists" means that for any two objects $B$ and $C$ there exists an object $D$ and morphisms $p:B\to D$ and $q:C\to D$ which form a coproduct diagram.  Do you understand how the first statement is true and the second statement is false in my example?

Comment: The difference is that to prove pushouts exist, you get to assume the existence of $A$, $f$, and $g$, which restricts the possibilities of what $B$ and $C$ can be.

Comment: I understand now that a pushout doesn't automatically gives a coproduct. For that you need an initial object, and I thank you. However, I still don't understand your "counter example". I don't think that a pushout with one object and one arrow makes sense any more than a coproduct with one object and one arrow.

Comment: In the statement of "pushouts exist", nothing requires the objects $A,B,$ and $C$ or the morphisms $f$ and $g$ to be distinct (or for $D$, $p$, and $q$ to be distinct from them).  All that is required is that for all such tuples $(A,B,C,f,g)$ there exists $(D,p,q)$ satisfying the definition of a pushout.  In the case of my example category, there don't exist any such tuples $(A,B,C,f,g)$ except those with $A=B=C$ and $f=g=id_A$.

Comment: I understand that. But your category has two degenerate pushouts with two degenarate coproducts "contained" in them. Mac Lane page 66 calls the "coproduct" of a pushout, a coproduct over A. In Set, S union T is a coproduct over S intersection T, but it is not an ordinary coproduct, while the disjoint union of S & T is an ordinary coproduct, but it is not a coproduct over S intersection T. See Tom Leinster "Basic Category Theory" page 131 (exists online).

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what your point is.  My category was just an example of a category in which all pushouts exist but not all coproducts exist.

Comment: I'm sorry we don't understand each other. I'm not sure how to fix it. Can you instead tell me how to get Math formulas into these comments? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: See https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thanks for the link! Even though I still don't understand your counter example, you helped me clear my initial confusion. Perhaps eventually I'll understand your point.

Comment: @alexanderyaacov Perhaps to understand Eric Wofsey's example you could see it spelled out very explicitly. The category $C$ is given by $Ob(C)=\{A, B\}$ and $Hom(A,B)= \emptyset$, $Hom(A,A)=pt$, $Hom(B,B)=pt$. Then any diagram $X \gets Y \to Z$ is necessarily of the form $X \gets X \to X$, where all the maps are the identity and $X$ is either $A$ or $B$. Clearly, $X$ is the pushout of this diagram, so all pushouts exist. But not all coproducts exist. Suppose we have a coproduct $A \oplus B$. So $A \oplus B$ is either $A$ or $B$. But then we have maps $A \to A \oplus B$ and $B \to A \oplus B$..

Comment: And why assume that coproduct A+B should exist? Just like there is no pushout which includes both A & B, so there is no coproduct which includes both A & B. What is difficult about that? All this back and forth revolves around one point, which is obvious to you but not to me.

Comment: @alexanderyaacov We assume it exists to arrive at a contradiction (i.e. to prove it doesn't exist). The point is to prove that categories exist that have every pushout but not all coproducts. Saying "there is no pushout that includes $A$ and $B$" doesn't mean the category doesn't have all pushouts

Comment: I finally get your point. The definition of "a category has all coproducts" is that all pairs of objects have their coproduct. So in a discrete category with more than one object this is not true. And the definition of "a category has all pushouts" is that all pairs of arrows with the same source etc., and this is true in any discrete category, even the empty category. Let me know if I got it right.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.